# Programmatically uploading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the jQuery file upload plugin which has an [API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) to programmatically upload files. The documentation writes:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: filesList});
```

The problem is that I don't know what `filesList` should be. I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: ['/Users/bob/Desktop/test.png']});
```

What should `filesList` be exactly?

Comment: You certainly cannot upload any file from the user's computer like that. Where would that lead.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), the "Example: Non-HTTP synchronous request"

Comment: Yes, that could work from a locally running script to fetch a file. But you cannot use it to upload files to a remote server.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Hum. So why is the API provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API):

> The second argument must be an object with an array (or array-like list) of File or Blob objects as files property.

You can get file objects using the files property of a file type input or the HTML5 File API.

For more detail regarding working with the FileAPI and file inputs see:
[MDC - Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: "You can get file objects using the files property of a file type input or the HTML5 File API." -> That's exactly my question. What is the relevant API/syntax to fetch files?

Comment: I should point out that grabbing a file from the client without user selecting it is not achievable because of the security implications.

Comment: I understand that. But why is the API provided then?

Comment: The API provides access to read the data within a file once it has been provided by the user. This means that client-side code can perform processes on files like resizing images or parsing content without posting to a server.

Comment: That's not what is said. "However it is also possible to upload files programmatically for browsers with support for XHR file uploads"

Comment: You can indeed programmatically upload files with the XMLHttpObject. However the act of getting the contents of a file to perform the upload with still requires user interaction. There would be very detrimental security implications of allowing client side script to read arbitrary files off the client file system.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'm not interested in the contents of the file. I just want to **programmatically upload a file**, as the title of my question says.

Comment: Then you will need to get the user to select a file, either with a file input or drag drop operation to start the process.

Comment: Well that's not my definition of "programmatic". For me "programmatically" implies no user interaction.

Comment: It seems the disctiction between the separate processes of selecting a file and uploading its contents have caused some confusion here. I'm afraid If you want to read files from the local file system without any user interaction then you will have to use a propitiatory technology such as ActiveX.

Answer (score 9):

ridiculous example :) that works !

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fileupload"></div>
<input class="zz" type="file" name="files[]"  multiple><br />
<input class="zz" type="file" name="files[]"  multiple><br />
<input class="zz" type="file" name="files[]"  multiple><br />
<input class="zz" type="file" name="files[]"  multiple><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input id="envoi_fax" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start"> <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i><span>Start upload</span>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script> 
$('document').ready(function () {
    var mycars = new Array();

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url:'server/php/',
        dataType: 'json',
        singleFileUploads: false,
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });

    $('.zz').bind('change', function (e) {
        var f;
        f = e.target.files || [{name: this.value}];
        mycars.push(f[0]);
    });

    $("#envoi_fax").click(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: mycars});
    });
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Comment: I really want to give this 5+ Up Votes.  I just couldn't wrap my head around how to create the file listing and/or access the list used by the example properties.  Thank you sooooo much for the example!!

Comment: I really want to give this one upvote but I agree that the answer would really benefit from some explanation.

Comment: Short explanation.. He keeps track of the files that will be uploaded by adding the files in the mycars array everytime a "change" event is raised for any of the fileinputs (all of them has a class "zz"). The click event for the submit button ("#envoi_fax") calls the fileupload widget's "send" method passing a javascript object that contains the "mycars" array.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you

```
The second argument must be an object with an array (or array-like list) of File
or Blob objects as files property.
```

while linking File to [Mozilla's DOM File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File)

You should supply an array of these objects